# Select a pandas dataframe row where column has minimum value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to select a row in Pandas DatFrame where a column has the lowest value. There should have an easy way of doing that, but so far I didn't find.

Suppose this dataframe:

```
>>> print(df.head())
    N   M  S
0  10  42  4
1  39  22  2
2  11  52  4
3  97  42  2
4  66  72  1
```

How do I get the row where a column has the minimum value? For example, how do I get the row where column 'S' has value 1?

Comment: `df[df.S==df.S.min()]`

Comment: That's very simple and elegant, thanks @ansev ! Do you min to write that as a solution so I can accept it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A column name of df.S works but a column name of df.T doesn't work. df.T invokes the Transpose operation because it takes namespace precedence. Here's [@ansev answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58684919/5817128) using literals instead.

```
df[df['S']==df['S'].min()]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df.S==df.S.min()]
```

or

```
df[df['S'].eq(df['S'].min())]
```

Comment: That also works to get the row for the max value! In my case I had to add a `.drop_duplicates()` after that, there were more than one row with the same S value.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(df.loc[df['S']==df['S'].min(),:])
```

Comment: Thanks, @giulio! Your solution is equivalent to @ansev 's, but a bit more verbose.

Comment: @heitor It's python philosophy: *explicit is better than implicit* :) welcome